# Hide Progress Dialog from background-fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, progressdialog

I'm encountering the following problem. I implemented a navigation with tabs and viewpager to swipe through my fragments. This is working fine so far.
But the fragments are all loading data via Async Task and for that they are showing an progress dialog. Which is self is also working as it should. My problem is, that because of the Viewpager not only the actual fragment is loaded but also the one next to it. So I see wrong progress dialog.
Is there any way, to achieve a behavior that the progress dialog stays visible for it's fragment (so, that the user is informed, when he moves to the next tab before the async task finished loading) but not anywhere else?

Hope it's clear, what I wanted to say.
Thanks for your help.

Best wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The progress dialog can be a "dialog" that hangs out in front of everything, or it can be a View that sits in place.  So, my advice would be to make either a full screen (or just partial screen) layout that sits in your fragment and displays the progress dialog. It will move aside with the rest of the fragment if the user moves to a different fragment.  If you set it at the top Z level, make it full screen and capture all taps to it (and swallow them so they don't cascade down into the layouts beneath in the z-order) I believe you'll have exactly what you're describing as your desired result.

The key is not to use ProgressDialog dynamically in code, but rather just the View version of it that you just place in your XML.

Edit:
I'm talking about one of these...

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
```

Comment: Do you have a link for an example? Tried it with adding a self made dialog fragment, but as it didn't work, I guess that's not what you meant.

Comment: you're overthinking this (no offense).  No need for Fragments here. Just use a progress view (if you're using eclipse you can just drag one into your layout in the layout tool that has all the different Views for you to drag n drop right into your View). Then just build a layout around it that prevents interaction with the stuff behind.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the point how build a layout that prevents interaction with the stuff behind. Just using a LinearLayout for example around the progress view that fills parent in width and height? And set it's visibilty to gone after the operatrion finished?

Comment: precisely. just capture all touches to that layout and don't let them move on into the stuff beneath.